# Partition function of quadrupole?

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, partition-function, multipole-expansion

I would like to compute the partition function Z for the quadrupole moment, but it is not as easy as the one for the dipole. Could anyone help please?

Comment: The partition function is a property of a statistical ensemble. What statistical ensemble are you considering?

Comment: canonical ensemble

Comment: Ok, so what properties do the elements of the ensemble have? Are they stationary or moving? Do they have an electric dipole moment? What about a magnetic dipole moment? Or an electric quadrupole moment, or a magnetic quadrupole moment? Do they interact with each other in a nontrivial way? There is no such thing as "the partition function for the quadrupole moment". The partition function is a property of an **ensemble**, and the total macroscopic quadrupole moment is, potentially, something that can be derived from the partition function for that ensemble.

Comment: I apologize, I realize I haven't been clear at all. I have a system at fixed temperature (canonical ensemble), which is made of non interacting, non moving molecules, each one having a zero permanent dipole, but a nonzero quadrupole. The system is acted upon by a uniform, constant electric field, and any particle is independent, so that I only care about one particle. The situation is semiclassical.

Comment: In the case in which there is only a nonzero dipole, we can easily find the partition function for the dipole in the electric field (with the Hamiltonian H=-pE), so we can get the free energy and so also the average of the dipole moment operator. I wonder if something similar can be done in the case of the electric quadrupole only.

Comment: If you have the Hamiltonian of a stationary electric quadrupole in a constant electric field, then you should have everything that you need.